# How to earn Qatar airways air miles without actually flying

Tags: canada, airlines, qatar-airways, oneworld

I would like to make a round trip on Qatar Airways economy between Montreal (YUL) and Kolkata (CCU). Now this would cost me 85000 [miles](https://qmiles.qatarairways.com/ffponline/ffp-online/MileageCalculator.jsf).

What is the cheapest way to acquire these miles without actually flying on Qatar/One world airlines throughout the year. Are there any credit card sign up bonuses or something else that I can use to earn these 85000 points.

Comment: Why do you have to earn the miles with Qatar? Why not earn them with one of the schemes which do hand out miles like candy to US credit card holders, then do a oneworld redemption on Qatar?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I am Canadian, so cannot get a US credit card

Comment: Have you reviewed the [Earning Qmiles](http://www.qatarairways.com/PrivilegeClub/privilege%20club%20earning%20qmiles.page) page? As you should know by now, questions on StackExchange are expected to demonstrate prior research effort on the part of the questioner. There are no realistic options for accrual except by flying QR or one of its partners, as there are no retail or financial partners in Canada and the points from hotel and car rental could take you decades to accumulate.

Comment: You still haven't clarified why it needs to be Qatar miles (qmiles), and not miles with one of the many (mostly oneworld) carriers who can book reward seats on Qatar flights

Comment: Yes it can be one world miles so long as they allow me to fly qatar airways

Comment: Note that award travel is subject to availability. So if you aren't flexible with respect to time and date, you might better be off just buying a ticket for your connection. Also, on award travel, you still pay taxes and fees, which are sometimes 90% of the ticket price.

Answer (score 3):

You could stay a lot of nights at one of any number of [hotels](http://www.qatarairways.com/PrivilegeClub/Partners.page?PartnerCategory=Hotels&mid=7&sid=1) and/or [rent cars](http://www.qatarairways.com/PrivilegeClub/Partners.page?PartnerCategory=Car%20Rentals&mid=7&sid=1) similarly.

For credit cards, your only option that I can find is the [RBC British Airways Visa Infinite](http://www.rbcroyalbank.com/credit-cards/travel-credit-cards/british-airways-credit-card.html) which has points that can be redeemed for flights on oneworld airlines.  Alternatively you could use [an American Express](http://thepointsguy.com/2012/12/the-top-travel-credit-card-offers-for-canadians/) to generate points and then purchase the flight through their travel planners using points.

Looking through [Qatar's bank partners](http://www.qatarairways.com/PrivilegeClub/Partners.page?PartnerCategory=Banks%20and%20Credit%20cards&mid=7&sid=1) there's no options listed for Canadian residents as most are based in Qatar/the Middle East, Southern Asia (India and Sri Lanka) or the U.S.

Answer (score 1):

Neglecting the fact that collecting Qatar miles may not be your best option to fly with Qatar/OneWorld, the best option you have, living in Canada, is probably to collect Starpoints (from Starwood Preferred Guest loyalty progam)

Starpoints can be transferred at 20k:25k (1:1.25) to Qatar, and there are options in Canada to acquire Starpoints without actually staying with SPG.

1. Signing up for SPG credit card by American Express
2. Signing up for any credit card by American Express that earns Membership Rewards points, which can be transferred to Starpoints at 2:1 (in Canada)

(Canadian) SPG credit card typically has a sign-up bonus of 20-25k Starpoints, and the Membership Rewards points earning cards has a larger range, around 25-50k MR points.